# Realm VerfiyError on Android KitKat

Tags: android, realm

I just got started with using Realm.  When running my app, Realm works fine on my Lollipop device, and my Marshmallow device. When running the app on a KitKat device (Samsung Tablet), the application crashes and returns this:

```
 E/UncaughtException: java.lang.VerifyError: io/realm/Realm
```

The error is caused by a line in my ApplicationSingleton class:

```
public class ApplicationSingleton extends Application {

@Override
public void onCreate() {
    super.onCreate();
    Realm.init(getApplicationContext()); //This crashes on KitKat but works fine on other devices
    RealmConfiguration realmConfiguration = new RealmConfiguration.Builder().name("HomeNET").schemaVersion(0).deleteRealmIfMigrationNeeded().build();
    Realm.setDefaultConfiguration(realmConfiguration);
}
}
```

I have added this class to my manifest file.

Anyone have idea's on what could be causing this issue, and what I could try?

Answer (score 0):

With reference to this thread on Realm GitHub: https://github.com/realm/realm-java/issues/3071

My app now works, after adding the MultiDex.install(this) line to my Application class:

```
public class ApplicationSingleton extends Application {
@Override
public void onCreate() {
    super.onCreate();
    MultiDex.install(this); //Source: https://github.com/realm/realm-java/issues/3071
    Realm.init(getApplicationContext()); 
    RealmConfiguration realmConfiguration = new RealmConfiguration.Builder().name("HomeNET").schemaVersion(0).deleteRealmIfMigrationNeeded().build();
    Realm.setDefaultConfiguration(realmConfiguration);
}
```

}

Comment: `MultiDex.install(this)` should be in `attachBaseContext()` afaik.